# add ::before 'content' to CSS class if value of class content is less than the value of 10

Tags: jquery, html, css, prepend

I am trying to prepend (i think thats the correct word to use) a "0" to the value of days in the screenshot here that are less than 10:

[Screenshot of current class and item in question](http://pbrd.co/1INAGpX)

I have the basic structure of the CSS to add the preceeding "0" value, but I just don't know how to add it ONLY IF the value is less than 10. As you can see I successfully added it to the entire class, but it also adds to the "11" value as well which I do not want.

Any help is VERY appreciated.

Michael

Comment: Not sure why my original post was marked -1 but okkkkk. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather do it with jquery

```
$(".target-div").each(function(){
 $(this).html(($(this).html<10?"0":"")+$(this).html());
});
```

Here .target-div is date div

Comment: BINGO! Thanks my friend, and dAm$ was that quick. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd love to upvote, but my reputation is currently too low, sorry! I will though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add some markup, then I would wrap the day with a `span`. Like so:

```
<div class="evo_date">
    <div class="start">
        <span>4</span>
        <em>Feb</em>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then run this jQuery snippet:

```
$(".evo_date .start span").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length == 1) {
        $(this).text("0" + $(this).text());
    }
});
```

Try it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/er0sh9bg/

Comment: I tested your version our as well Kenneth and it works just as well. I appreciate you guys so much. Thanks for the fiddle as well.

Comment: I'd love to upvote, but my reputation is currently too low, sorry! I will though.